# apache rewrite rule to flow requests for all .php files to a specific file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a simple website. I'm using a template file (template.php), which has all the shared HTML, and accepts a parameter (say 'page'). then opens the page file and includes the page in itself. something like this: (the code is just a prototype. no validation/filtering is required).

```
<?php
//template.php
?>
<html>
    <body>
      <div>my web site</div> <!-- shared by all pages -->
      <div> <!-- specific page contents -->
         <?php include($_REQUEST['page']); ?>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

what the .htaccess file should be like, so the request for PHP files, goes through the template.php file with the 'page' parameter as the name of the requested file name?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ template.php?page=$0 [L]
```

The additional `RewriteCond` conditions are to exclude requests that can be mapped to existing files (`-f`) or directories (`-d`).

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure about this, because:

1. I need this rule to be applied on only .php files
2. my .php files already exist (because I am including them).